# Is combining Odds Ratios with Relative Risk in a Meta-Analysis Possible?

Tags: meta-analysis, odds-ratio, relative-risk

Can I combine ORs and RRs using generic inverse variance if the the event rare?

There appears to be simple methods for converting ORs into RRs so would I do the conversion first and then apply the generic inverse variance? Or would I simply treat the effect measures as equivalent and enter them along with their standard errors into RevMan for example?

https://www.bmj.com/content/348/bmj.f7450.full?ijkey=NHT1YVsoX1RCm8r&keytype=ref

Any insight very welcome.

Many thanks,

Autumn

Comment: You can convert risk ratios to odds ratios or the other way round, providing you know the probability or odds for one of the treatments (including the control case).